# Query not grouping by what I want

Tags: sql, oracle

I am having some trouble with this query :

```
select 
case 
    when d.deal_numadm!=0 and d.deal_numadm is not null 
        then 'MA' || d.deal_nummas || '_' || d.ntt_id 
    when d.deal_numadm=0 or d.deal_numadm is null 
        then 'Master' || d.deal_nummas || '_' || d.ntt_id 
end as node_id, 
sum(cva.cva), sum(dva.dva), d.deal_numadm, d.deal_nummas
from acc_processed_cva cva 
left outer join acc_processed_dva dva on dva.deal_id = cva.deal_id 
join acc_deals d on d.deal_id = cva.deal_id and d.deal_scope='Y' 
join dt_runs r on r.run_id = cva.run_id and r.deal_cnt_id = d.deal_cnt_id 
where r.run_id=57 and d.deal_nummas=10700 and d.ntt_id = 1731413
group by d.ntt_id, d.deal_nummas, d.deal_numadm, d.deal_cnt_id, d.ntt_id;
```

It returns these rows :

```
NODE_ID             SUM(CVA.CVA)    SUM(DVA.DVA)    DEAL_NUMADM DEAL_NUMMAS
MA10700_1731413     953180          1373440         22012       10700
Master10700_1731413 4886330         4318999         0           10700
MA10700_1731413     1654            1192            12054       10700
MA10700_1731413     4               (null)          83442       10700
MA10700_1731413     14              1093            10775       10700
MA10700_1731413     963             (null)          10779       10700
```

However, I want to group these rows by `DEAL_NUMMAS`, so I should really have only 2 rows.

I have tried to remove the `d.deal_numadm` in the `GROUP BY` expression, but it failed with this error :

`ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"`

**CLARIFICATION**

Above, DEAL_NUMADM is only there to show that they are different for each row returned.

What I want is this :

```
NODE_ID             SUM(CVA.CVA)    SUM(DVA.DVA)    DEAL_NUMMAS
MA10700_1731413     955815          1375725         10700
Master10700_1731413 4886330         4318999         10700
```

with the first row being the sum of rows 1, 3, 4, 5 and 6.

How can I achieve the result I want ?

Comment: There's only one value in` DEAL_NUMMAS`, why do you expect 2 rows in your result? Maybe you can simply do a `min(DEAL_NUMMAS)` when you remove `DEAL_NUMMAS` from GROUP BY

Comment: If you have `deal_numadm` in the select list you have to group by it too, as you've seen. If you want a single row for each `ntt_id` and `deal_nummas` then you have to remove `deal_numadm` completely, or decide which of the 5 values to keep, as an aggregate. Can't really suggest what to change without knowing how you want to resolve that conundrum.

Comment: As per your expected results seems like grouping by node_id could solve your problem, and try to remove others from group by clause unless very necessary except for d.deal_nummas (as it your expected result) you may use MAX function in select. Reason it fail when u remove them from group-by is that you need to keep them in aggregate function or they should appear in group-by clause. So plan wisely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok , I figured it out. The query that does what I want :

```
select
case 
    when d.deal_numadm!=0 and d.deal_numadm is not null 
        then 'MA' || d.deal_nummas || '_' || d.ntt_id 
    when d.deal_numadm=0 or d.deal_numadm is null 
        then 'Master' || d.deal_nummas || '_' || d.ntt_id 
end as node_id, 
sum(cva.cva), sum(dva.dva)
from acc_processed_cva cva 
left outer join acc_processed_dva dva on dva.deal_id = cva.deal_id 
join acc_deals d on d.deal_id = cva.deal_id and d.deal_scope='Y' 
join dt_runs r on r.run_id = cva.run_id and r.deal_cnt_id = d.deal_cnt_id 
where r.run_id=57 and d.deal_nummas=10700 and d.ntt_id = 1731413
group by d.ntt_id, d.deal_nummas, case 
    when d.deal_numadm!=0 and d.deal_numadm is not null 
        then 'MA' || d.deal_nummas || '_' || d.ntt_id 
    when d.deal_numadm=0 or d.deal_numadm is null 
        then 'Master' || d.deal_nummas || '_' || d.ntt_id 
end;
```